# tadoquery post: "cannot update non-nullable column with null" on identity column

Tags: sql-server, delphi, post, ado, identity

I am trying to use a TAdoquery with MS SQL Server in a legacy delphi project. 
The dataset contains a field that represents identity column in the SQL table. It has `AutogenerateValue = arAutoInc` and ProviderFlags `[pfInWhere, pfInKey]`. It also has `Required = false`.

After doing `adoquery.Append` I prefill fields and try to do `adoquery.Post` but get this error: 
    `Non-nullable column cannot be updated to Null`

All non-nullable fields are set to non-null before post, so the identity column is the only suspect. The TADOQuery has no joins (simple Select * from my_table), but it has look up fields and calculated fields, which may be null. For lookup fields and calculated fields I removed provider Flags to ensure those fields do not appear in the insert or update statement.

The identity field is NULL immediately before post, I see no insert command firing on the server in the Profiler, instead I just get this error.

- Is it possible to preview the sql statement generated by the Tadoquery to insert a new row ?

Comment: Rather than try to preview what Sql the TAdoQuery generates, you might do better to look at what Sql is actually sent to the server using MS Sql Server's profiler tool, because the MDac layer often turns what you'd expect to be straightforward INSERT/SELECT/UPDATE statements into calls to temporary parameterized stored procedures the layer creates.

Comment: Is the identity field readonly?

Comment: Thanks MartynA, the problem is that Profiler doesn't show anything at all. Seems like nothing goes to the server after I hit `post` ( I selected "all events" and still nothing )

Comment: Uwe, yes identity field is readonly

Comment: @user3243551 Have you checked that you can see anything happening in the profiler when your project executes a SELECT or UPDATE?

Comment: @MartynA i see selects & updates but don't see insert when I click post. Seems like there is no insert.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the issue was of course unrelated to the identity column. 
The initial sql was `select * from myTable`, which meant that it also loaded a couple of extra columns that were not bound to any grid column in my DBGridEh. 
After replacing * with an explicit list of the columns that I needed the INSERT worked.